# Turkey Dinners For A Group of 140 People

Tags: turkey, bulk-cooking

I am cooking turkey dinner for 140 people at our church. My meal consist of turkey, stuffing balls, mashed potatoes & gravy, green beans, noodles in gravy, and cole slaw. I am not sure of the amounts of food I should cook and your advice would be very helpful.   Thank You

Comment: "... and cole slaw"? Quantities will largely depend on who is eating.  A Football team, or the local Cub Scouts? A Women's Club, or the Contestants in the Boston Marathon? "It's all relative." More information would certainly be helpful.

Comment: It might be too late, but there's a question about planning for 100 people that might be useful : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75505/67

Answer (score 1):

Pound per person for bone-in birds, so 140 pounds of turkeys (6-9 whole birds)

Sides are a half cup per person — 60 pounds potatoes, 18 heads of cabbage for slaw, 12 pounds pasta, and 70 cups stuffing.

This is the [site](https://www.chef-menus.com/food-quantity-chart.html) I use

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but in answering another 'bulk-cooking' question, I stumbled upon a website with advice specifically for turkey dinners (with a note that this is for 'holiday' dinners, that might be more generous than usual):

http://www.ellenskitchen.com/turkey/planshop.html

In case of link rot (although some characters didn't come through ... I suspect 1 1/4 to 1 1/2):

> **Whole turkey and turkey parts- turkey only**
>
> Allow for 1 pound of uncooked turkey per person when purchasing a whole turkey up to 12-14 pounds or turkey pieces (legs, thighs, etc); allow at least to 3/4 pound per person when purchasing a whole turkey weighing over     14 pounds.
>
> Reduce the total amount by 20 percent if you will have a server for the meat (not self serve) and want no leftovers.
>
> Increase the total amount by 50% if you want lots of leftovers or expect lots of heavy eaters
>
> **Prestuffed frozen turkey** (do NOT prestuff and freeze your own, it is unsafe)
>
> Allow 1� to 1� pounds per person when purchasing a prestuffed turkey.
>
> **Turkey breast or boneless roast**
>
> Allow 2/3 pound per person when purchasing a bone-in turkey breast, which usually weighs between 4 and 8 pounds (4 pounds for each 6 people)
>
> Allow 1/2 pound per person when purchasing a boneless turkey breast or roast, which usually weighs between 4 and 8 pounds (4 pounds for each 8 people).

To condense/summarize some of the rest of that page:

- dressing or stuffing: 1/2 to 3/4 cup per person (6 ounces)
- mashed potatoes: a pound raw of potato for each 3 persons for mashed potatoes.
- vegetable casseroles and/or sweet potatoes and/or winter squash: 1/2 cup or 4 ounces by weight for each vegetable.  A #10 can holds 24-25 servings. This is an inexpensive place to bulk up the meal, maybe corn AND sweet potatoes AND peas with onions or green bean casserole AND one or two others.
- gravy: 1/3 cup is best, 1/4 cup minimum
- cranberry relish: 1 pound per 5-6 persons
- rolls: 4 for each 3 persons minimum, up to 1 1/2 per person
- butter: 3 pounds for each 100 people

... and notes to see the dessert and drinks pages for more info on those