# Need to cook pasta for 200 people

Tags: pasta, bulk-cooking

I need to make fettuccine alfredo with chicken,it's for my daughters Quinceñera. I need to know how much pasta and chicken need to purchase to make for each person approximately  2ounces .

Comment: You want to know how to **measure** it? Or do you want to know how much you need to buy to feed this many people? Measuring is easy... by weight.

Comment: How much I need to buy

Comment: We need more information. Are you doing a main dish pasta with bits of chicken in it or are you doing a piece of chicken with a side of pasta? Please use the edit link to add information to your question. It's helpful to know what sorts of people you have at the dinner. If it's mostly big men, they'll want to eat more... if it's a bunch of ladies and kids, they'll eat less.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43353/67 ... and you might also want to look at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12068/67

Comment: I don't get this. If you need 2 ounces p.p. that's 400 ounces.

Answer (score 2):

To really get an answer you should definitely do a test dish. Prepare 1 or 2 portions as you usually do at home. If you approve the result just multiple the  ingredient quantity. To me it is impossible to give you a better answer as your portioning has to depend on how filling the sauce is as well. Also doing a test of the recipe will be helpful for your peace of mind on the big day.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A standard serving of meat is 4 ounces. If this is the main dish you will need 400oz or 25lbs of chicken. If it is a side dish I would half that.

Comment: A "serving" and "what people actually eat" aren't the same thing, unfortunately. Could you address this somewhat? Also, the question is asking about both pasta and chicken, not chicken alone.

Comment: It's also worth noting that cooked chicken weight =/= raw chicken weight.  I typically say 4 ounces raw gives about 3 ounces cooked.